# stacking 2d array onto the part of 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have oned 3d numpy array.

```
d = np.ones((3,2,2))

'''
array([[[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]])
'''
```

And want to stack 2d array onto the part of 3d array.

```
# tried
d[0] = np.vstack((d[0], np.array([1,3])))
```

I expected

```
array([[[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],
        [1., 3.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

But it occurred

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (2,2)
```

I guess indexing 3d array returns the copied part array of the whole array.
 But still no idea how to make possible.

---

Similar Problem

3d numpy empty array

```
d = np.empty((3,0,2))

d
# array([], shape=(3, 0, 2), dtype=float64)
```

Tried same approach as above one but 'empty' array this time.

```
d[0] = np.vstack( (d[0], np.array([1,3])) )
```

I expected

```
array([[[1., 3.],

       [],

       []]])
```

But it doesn't make any change

```
print(d)
# []
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `numpy` isn't designed to store jagged data

Comment: If you want a data structure designed for multidimensional data with the opportunity to expand arbitrary dimensions, have a look at [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) / [`netCDF4`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html)

Comment: `d[0]` or `d[0,:,:]` is a 2x2 array.  `vstack` makes a 3x2.  But you can't 'put' that back into the 2x2 `d[0]` slot.  `numpy` arrays don't grow like that.  In the second case `d[0]` is a 0x2 array, `vstack` makes a 1x2.  That does fit in a 0x2 slot (by `broadcasting`), but it is still a 0x2 slot.

Comment: `np.empty` is just like `np.ones`, but just doesn't initialize the values to 1.  `np.ones((3,0,2))` would behave the same way.  `np.empty` is not 'empty' in the same way that the list `[]` is.  Don't confuse the two uses of `empty`.  While it's possible to set a dimension of an array to 0 like this, it's rarely useful.

Comment: `d = [np.ones((2,2)) for _ in range(3)]` creates a list of 2d arrays.  Now `d[0]` can be changed into a (3,2) array.